# Python and Pygame method can't be found when clearly defined?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create my own Python Code( With the help of Youtuber RootofTheNull) and I'm getting this error.

Can someone help?

```
import pygame
from colors import *


class Block (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def set_message(text):
        global message,previous_message
        message = font.render(text,True,black,white)
        previous_message=message

    def __init__(self, color =blue, width=64, height = 64):

        super( Block, self ).__init__()


        self.image = pygame.Surface((width, height))
        self.image.fill( color )
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.sound=pygame.mixer.Sound("")
        self.origin_x = self.rect.centerx
        self.origin_y = self.rect.centery

    def set_properties(self):
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()

        self.origin_x = self.rect.centerx
        self.origin_y = self.rect.centery

    def set_position (self, x, y):
        self.rect.x = x-self.origin_x
        self.rect.y = y-self.origin_y
    def set_image( self, filename = None ):
        if (filename !=None ):
            self.image = pygame.image.load (filename)
            self.set_properties()

    def play_sound(self):
        self.sound.play(-1)

if ( __name__ == "__main__"):
    pygame.init()
    window_size = window_width, window_height = 512, 384
    window = pygame.display.set_mode(window_size, pygame.RESIZABLE)

    pygame.display.set_caption( " Cloud Runner ")
    window.fill ( white )
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    frames_per_second = 60

    block_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
    a_block = Block()
    a_block.play_sound()
    a_block.set_image("beaten_brick_tiled.png")
    a_block.set_position( window_width/2, window_height/2)
    another_block = Block( red )
    another_block.set_position(100,100)
    block_group.add(a_block, another_block)


    font = pygame.font.SysFont("Times New Roman, Arial",30)

    message = previous_message = None
    set_message("Hello World!")


    running = True

    while ( running ):
        pygame.event.pump()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if (event.type == pygame.QUIT) or \
            (event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN and  \
            (event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE or event.key ==pygame.K_q)):
                running = False
            if (event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION):
                mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
                a_block.set_position(mouse_pos[0],mouse_pos[1])


        clock.tick (frames_per_second)
        window.fill ( white )
        if (message != previous_message):
            set_message(message)

        window.blit(message,(window_width/2 - message.get_rect().width/2,window_height/2-100))
        block_group.draw( window )
        pygame.display.update()

    pygame.quit()
```

The error:

```
 File "C:/Users/kedz0_000/Desktop/Python Crap/CloudRunner.py", line 64, in <module>
    set_message('Hello World!')
NameError: name 'set_message' is not defined
```

Comment: looks like it's not a global function, but a member of the class

Answer (score 2):

You have `set_message` as a method of `Block`. It doesn't seem to belong there

```
def set_message(text):
    global message, previous_message
    message = font.render(text, True, black, white)
    previous_message = message

class Block (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, color=blue, width=64, height=64):

        super( Block, self ).__init__()

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I fixed that, and that works fine. I have this now,

http://pastebin.com/Q1HKv76Z

and then its not moving still.

By chance, are you the John from the same video? RootoftheNull? Just wondering. XD